# Point to Google cloud datastore using Objectify

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Objectify library for Google cloud datastore, when I run my java app as app engine, it is inserting/ fetching data from local datastore. How to configure it to point to Google Cloud Datastore?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how to answer this question.

Objectify (v5) uses the standard GAE SDK API to connect to the datastore. If you run it in a local dev environment, it will talk to a local datastore. If you deploy it in a production app, it will talk to the "real" datastore.

Objectify v6 is a different story because it uses the new Cloud SDK and you can connect to any datastore with it. But v6 is in alpha, not ready for production, and it doesn't sound like you are using it.